# При начале обучения нейронной сети выходит ошибка: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Я запускаю нейронную сеть на keras, он вроде бы адекватно занружает изображения, но потом вылезает эта ошибка:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\ClassificationTraining\ClassificationTraining\ClassificationTraining.py", line 78, in <module>
    validation_steps= nb_val_samples // batch_size
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 181, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 601, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 595, in get
    inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 401, in get_index
    return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 1441, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 1916, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    dtype=self.dtype)
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`
```

Вот сам код:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

np.random.seed(42)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255)

train_dir = r"D:\Documents\Desktop\data\train"
val_dir = r"D:\Documents\Desktop\data\val"
test_dir = r"D:\Documents\Desktop\data\test"

images_height = 256,
images_width = 256,

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(images_height, images_width),
    batch_size=5,
    class_mode='binary'
    )

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(images_height, images_width),
    batch_size=3,
    class_mode='binary'
    )

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(images_height, images_width),
    batch_size=3,
    class_mode='binary'
    )

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), input_shape = (256, 256, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(30, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(30))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    )

batch_size = 3
nb_train_samples = 68
nb_val_samples = 11
nb_test_samples = 13


model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps= nb_val_samples // batch_size
    )

scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)
print("Аккуратность на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Я так понимаю, что он считает целое число за кортеж, но почему? В интернете предлагают закрыть двойными скобками, по типу ((64, 64)), но это не помогло. Ставил цифру вручную, но результат такой же. Ещё я удалил 77-ю строку, и ошибка перескочила на 76-ю. Я добавил [0] в конец, если вдруг он действительно выдаёт кортеж, но появилась такая ошибка:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\ClassificationTraining\ClassificationTraining\ClassificationTraining.py", line 79, in <module>
    validation_steps= val_steps[0],
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'
```

То есть, программа всё-таки понимает, что это число. Но что ей мешает? В общем, я не понимаю, что ей не нравится. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не работал с керасом, поэтому могу ошибаться. Но мне кажется, что проблема в этих строках:

```
images_height = 256,
images_width = 256,
```

Кажется, запятые нужно убрать. По крайней мере, беглый поиск по документации говорит, что `target_size` должен быть таплом интов, и я не вижу, чтобы он мог быть таплом таплов интов.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не заметил, когда сам смотрел! Проблема действительно была в этих двух запятых!